# Overriding an objects method in PHP at runtime

Tags: php, class, oop, object, overriding

Is it possible to "override" an **objects** method  in PHP? Example:

```
<?php
class Test {
    function Foobar() {
        echo "Foobar";
    }
}

$t = new Test();

// Replace the Foobar-method with new code
$t->Foobar() = function() {
    echo "New Code";
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you may not do it using [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

While you could probably do something similar using `__call()` as shown [here in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), or assigning anonymous functions to properties, I feel it would get ugly quite quickly and be difficult to follow and maintain.

If you want to override an objects method you should do it by extending the base class and creating a method of the same name, as shown in [Example #1 here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php).